# Bash: showing the larger distance between cities of a file of format origin_city:destiny_city:distance

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

The script will show the larger distance of this file, in this case is 995 (Barcelona:Sevilla:995).

The file format is (filename = distancias_sp.txt:

```
Barcelona:Valencia:350
Barcelona:Madrid:623
Valencia:Zaragoza:308
Madrid:Lugo:505
Barcelona:Sevilla:995
```

The output format must be:

```
The longest distance is between Barcelona and Sevilla: 995Km
```

How can this be done? Thank you :)

Comment: `sort` by column 3 (: separated) descending, then `head -1` to get the longest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -v FS=':' 'BEGIN{origin=""; dest=""; dist=0} {if($3>dist) {origin=$1;dest=$2;dist=$3}} END{print "The longest distance is between ",origin," and ",dest,": ",dist,"Km"}' distancias_sp.txt
```